# When redirecting subdomains to folders, how can I avoid folder-subdomain duplication for URLs with trailing slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have a strange problem with internal mod_rewrte redirects on Apache 2.4.

In my `.htaccess` file I redirect a subdomain `sub` to a folder `/sub` with the following directives:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!sub).*)$ /sub/$1  [NC]
```

Thos works perfectly for, say, `https://sub.mydomain.com/articles/` - the URL stays like this in the browser's address field and as expected the data from the location at `/sub/articles/index.html` are served/

However when I type in in the browser `https://sub.mydomain.com/articles` (note the missing slash) the URL is changed in the browser to `https://sub.mydomain.com/sub/articles/` (note the duplicated `sub` as folder *and* subdomain!).

I guess this is caused by Apache's default behavior to add a slash to slashless directory requests as *external* redirects. The adding of the slash is OK with me, but of course I want to avoid the folder-subdomain duplication. - How can I do this?

Comment: You probably won't be able to achieve that without turning [`DirectorySlash`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) off - with all its potential downsides / consequences. The alternative would be that you let the automatic external redirect to `https://sub.mydomain.com/sub/articles/` happen, and then catch that and redirect to `https://sub.mydomain.com/articles/` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is caused by mod_dir appending a slash (with a 301 redirect) to the directory after the rewrite has occurred, exposing the internally rewritten URL/directory.

The canonical URL therefore needs to be `/articles/` (with a trailing slash), not `/articles`. We can correct this with an external redirect *before* the rewrite occurs.

(This avoids you having to disable the `DirectorySlash` - which would still leave you with a canonicalization / duplicate content issue.)

For example, before the existing rewrite, test to see if the requested URL-path (that is missing a trailing slash) exists as a directory in the `/sub` directory and append a slash if that is the case.

```
# Redirect to append trailing slash if exists as a dir inside "/sub"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^((?!sub/).*[^/])$ /$1/  [R=301,L]
```

As an additional optimisation, you can avoid unnecessarily performing a filesystem check (which are relatively expensive) on static assets (that naturally do not end in a trailing slash) by excluding URLs that look like they have a file-extension. (This assumes you don't have physical directories that have, what looks like, a file extension, eg. `/sub/somedir.xyz`)

Add the following as the 2nd condition (*before* the filesystem check) in the above rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
```

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.mydomain.com$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^((?!sub).*)$ /sub/$1  [NC]
> ```

You should probably be using the `L` flag on this `RewriteRule` directive. (And the `NC` flag should be unnecessary.)

The regex `^((?!sub).*)$` excludes any URL-path that simply starts `sub`, which would include `/subfoo` and `/subbar`, etc. (which naturally prevents these directories from being accessible in the `/sub` directory). Any valid request would start `/sub/` (with a trailing slash), so should be included in the negative lookahead, as I did in the rule above.

If not already, consider also redirecting to remove `/sub/` from direct requests if this directory should be exposed/discovered.

Comment: Thanks for all the details! Your idea to add the slash beforehand makes sense!